# G_Signals handling non-Gobject types?

Tags: c, signals, glib, gobject

The only example I was able to find for creating and emitting new signals was on the [gnome developer site](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/howto-signals.html) which provides the following example:

```
file = g_object_new (MAMAN_FILE_TYPE, NULL);
g_signal_connect (file, "changed", G_CALLBACK (changed_event), NULL);
maman_file_write (file, buffer, strlen (buffer));
/* ------------------  */
file_signals[CHANGED] = 
  g_signal_newv ("changed",
                 G_TYPE_FROM_CLASS (gobject_class),
                 G_SIGNAL_RUN_LAST | G_SIGNAL_NO_RECURSE | G_SIGNAL_NO_HOOKS,
                 NULL /* closure */,
                 NULL /* accumulator */,
                 NULL /* accumulator data */,
                 g_cclosure_marshal_VOID__VOID,
                 G_TYPE_NONE /* return_type */,
                 0     /* n_params */,
                 NULL  /* param_types */);

/* ------------------  */
void maman_file_write (MamanFile    *self, const guchar *buffer, gssize        size)
{
  /* First write data. */
  /* Then, notify user of data written. */
  g_signal_emit (self, file_signals[CHANGED], 0 /* details */);
}
```

One thing I'm wondering is whether it's possible to emit signals which don't have a GObject as a source -- and whether it's possible to pass non-Gobject structures. 
For simplicity sake suppose I have a function that creates point objects and I want to emit a signal when a point has been created (suppose there is some GtkWidget that displays something when a point is created):

```
struct point {
    int x,y;
};

struct point *new_point(int x, int y) {
    struct point *my_point = malloc(sizeof(point)); 
    my_point->x= x;
    my_point->y= y;
    /* ??? 
    g_signal_emit "point-created" 
    send pointer to my_point as a parameter to listeners
    */
    return my_point;
}
```

Is there a way to make something akin to the lower work without all of the boiler plate that goes into creating a new G_OBJECT_TYPE ?

Comment: There doesn't have to be a lot of boilerplate for creating a GObject.  See https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/2.44/howto-gobject-code.html (the G_DEFINE_TYPE macro).

Comment: Hmm - I was under the impression it required initialize/finalize methods, class definitions and the type macros https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/2.44/howto-gobject.html. Is the answer otherwise that I can't emit a signal without a gobject as a reference?

Comment: You do need to provide instance and class init functions—see the docs for G_DEFINE_TYPE_EXTENDED for a more thorough explanation.  I don't consider those boilerplate because they are actually significant and change a lot for different types.  I don't know the answer about signals from non-gobjects (hence the comment instead of an answer), though I suspect it's not possible.

Comment: It's not useful if you need 50+ lines of code to pass 16 bytes. I think I'm going to say screw it to using any gobject signals which aren't built in to gtk.

Comment: It's more like 10 lines, but okay.  That said, emitting a signal in the constructor doesn't really make sense.  What you probably want to do is make a point a parameter to a signal you emit on another type (likely the instance of whatever method is calling `new_point`).  To do that, point doesn't need to be a GObject (or even registered with GType, though that is only one line of code).

Comment: The constructor was a simplified example -- can you provide an example of what you mean by: (make a point a parameter to a signal you emit on another type) ?

Comment: To create the signal you would do something like `g_signal_new ("foo", TYPE_BAR, G_SIGNAL_RUN_LAST, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, G_TYPE_NONE, 1, G_TYPE_POINTER);`, and to emit it something like `g_signal_emit_by_name (self, "foo", (Point*) point);`